# Distorted winform mono application on buildroot based embedded system

Tags: c#, mono, arm, embedded-linux, buildroot

I am trying to run a C#/VB.net programm on an embedded linux ARM system I build with buildroot. The applications runs but there are heavy distorted on my buildroot system. I created a very simple winforms application and compiled it using Visual Studio 2008 (tried 2017, same results). Running the same binary using mono brings the following results:

- X86 Linux-Mint VM : works fine
- ARM Raspbian Raspberry Pi 3+ : works fine
- ARM Buildroot Raspberry Pi 3+ : broken display
- ARM buildroot i.MX6 : broken display

I tried using different Xorg and mono versions without positive result.
Any ideas where to pinpoint the problem?

Here are 2 screenshots from the Raspbian and the buildroot one. Also some basic version infos I think that could be usefull.

[Raspbian, everythings fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgpkc.png)

[Buildroot, broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwXkh.png)

> Raspberry Pi ARM, working fine:
>
> ```
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -r
> 4.9.69-v7+
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Xorg -version
> X.Org X Server 1.18.4
> Release Date: 2016-07-19
> X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
> Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.26-v7+ armv7l Raspbian
>
> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mono --version
> Mono JIT compiler version 4.0.2 (Debian 4.0.2.5+dfsg-2~rpi1)
> ```
>
> NXP i.MX 6, distorted:
>
> ```
> # uname -r
> 4.1.15-F+S
>
> # Xorg -version
>
> X.Org X Server 1.19.6
> Release Date: 2017-12-20
> X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
> Build Operating System: Linux 4.8.13-100.fc23.x86_64 x86_64
>
> # mono --version
> Mono JIT compiler version 5.4.0.201 (tarball Mon Jul 30 11:46:19 CEST 2018)
> ```

Comment: Have you tried what's under "My forms are sized improperly"? https://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/winforms/

Comment: @ikkentim I just tried "export MONO_MWF_SCALING=disable". Same result. The same binary works with Raspbian just fine so I think it should be possible to fix the issue without changing the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
Bumping several library to a higher version and disabling the pango library did the trick.

libgdiplus 5.4 to 5.6
Cairo      1.14.10  to 1.15.12
pango      removed